# How To show product quantity in dropdown Magento

Tags: magento

I want to show Product  quantity in dropdown like 10,20,30 for according to product in magento please help what are i do

please help

thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide some code that we can work with.

Comment: This sounds very simple, please show some effort!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you create a new numeric custom attribute for your products so you can define the packsize/order multiple for each product.  Then go to this file;

```
app/design/frontend/YOURFOLDER/YOURTHEME/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

In this file, find this code;

```
<?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
    <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1<?php //echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
    <?php endif; ?>
```

And replace it with this;

```
<?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
   <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
   <?php 
   $qtymultiple = $_product->getData('your_attribute_code'); // Add your attribute_id here 
   if(($qtymultiple == 1) || (!$qtymultiple)) { // No need to anything ?>

       <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1<?php //echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />

   <?php } else { //qty multiple requirement ?>

   <select name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12">
   <?php 
   $countme = 1;
   while ($countme < 101) { // Define how many multiples of the number to offer
       echo '<option value="'.($qtymultiple*$countme).'">'.($qtymultiple*$countme).'</option>';
       $countme++;   
   } ?>
  </select>

 <?php } ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

This will show a select box with multiples instead of the free type qty box for products that have a value the custom attribute.